# Shell script that checks every X seconds if PID is running

Tags: bash, shell, pid

I must create a Shell script that checks every X seconds if a PID (process identifier) is running or not. It must run with this terminal command:

$ script [PID] [SECONDS]

I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a PID
read -a SECONDS

while(true)

    if [kill -s 0 $PID]
        then
            echo "PID $PID is running"
        exit 0;
    else
            echo "PID $PID is not running"

sleep $SECONDS
```

can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Please search for examples of while loops and if conditions in bash, there's millions out there. You syntax is completely off. Everything counts, especially spaces between "tokens".

Comment: There are numerous services available for starting and monitoring long-lived programs.

Answer (score 2):

There's `watch`, especially its `-g` option which makes `watch` exit if the output of the repeated command changes.

Other than that, what Mat said. Your grasp of Bash seems to be... in need of more training.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to check whether a process with a specific PID is running than using `kill`. Instead check the existence of the equivalent directory in /proc.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) <PID> <Seconds>"
  exit 1
fi

while true; do
  if [ -d /proc/$1 ]; then
    echo "PID $1 is running"
  else
    echo "PID $1 is not running"
  fi

  sleep $2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`pgrep` works well too.  It returns the PID of a process that matches the provided pattern

```
pgrep $proc_name > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "$proc_name doesn't exist"
fi
```